# Why is Element null vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can someone explain why this `console.log` output is `null` and how i can fix it?

```
    <template v-for="day in getMonthLength()" >

      <td >
        <input :id="day" type=number :value="dataa.value">
      </td>
     

      <td  v-if="getLastTd(day)"> <input type=number></td>
    </template>
```

....

```
getLastTd(day) {
console.log(document.getElementById(day));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

- Ideally within Vue to access elements you use refs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html
- Element is `null` because you have a `v-if` and it's not resulting in `true` therefore element is not shown.
- `v-if` needs to resolve to a boolean. Example `v-if="person.age > 18"`
- I'm guessing that the above is "test code". If you simply want to run a function it is easier to bind it to a click event rather in a `v-if`. Example `<button @click="getLastTd(day)">...`

Comment: that is not the point why it doesnt work, it is a test code

Comment: yes but the `v-if` needs to resolve as a boolean (i.e. `true` or `false`) your function is not returning anything. That means you have `v-if="undefined"` which is the same as false, therefore element won't show. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: that is not the problem, in my real code the function is returning a boolean and it still doesnt work. i think its a problem/conflict with the vue js rendering

Comment: @elias.xe can you please update the code to something similar to what you have in your real application? As you can see from my comments I thought your issue is with `v-if`